# what are the applications of the python reload function?

Tags: python

I have been wondering about the reload() function in python, which seems like it can lead to problems if used without care.

Why would you want to reload a module, rather than just stop/start python again?

I imagine one application might be to test changes to a module interactively.

Comment: discussion about "problems if used without care", and possible solutions:  http://lists.canonical.org/pipermail/kragen-hacks/2002-January/000302.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

reload is useful for reloading code that may have changed in a Python module. Usually this means a plugin system.

Take a look at this link:

http://www.codexon.com/posts/a-better-python-reload

It will tell you the shortcomings of reload and a possible fix.

Comment: thanks, it was exactly this kind of class/instance question I was wondering about.

Comment: thanks for this post. unfortunately your link is no longer working

Answer (score 4):

> I imagine one application might be to test changes to a module interactively.

That's really the only use for it. From the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reload):

> This is useful if you have edited the module source file using an external editor and want to try out the new version without leaving the Python interpreter.

Comment: and you also might have variables or functions defined in the shell, and restarting it means you have to define them again

Answer (score 1):

Adding a link to my new [reimport](http://code.google.com/p/reimport/) module that was released yesterday. This provides a more thorough reimport than the reload() builtin. With this reimport you can be sure that class changes and function updates will get reflected in all instances and callbacks.

http://code.google.com/p/reimport/